# Calling C++ function from Inside Python function

Tags: python, c++

In R we can use Rcpp to call a cpp function as the one below:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP critcpp(SEXP a, SEXP b){
     NumericMatrix X(a);
     NumericVector crit(b);
     int p = XtX.ncol();
          NumericMatrix critstep(p,p);
     NumericMatrix deltamin(p,p);
     List lst(2);
         for (int i = 0; i < (p-1); i++){
            for (int j = i+1; j < p; j++){
               --some calculations
             }
          }
          lst[0] = critstep;
          lst[1] = deltamin;
          return lst;
}
```

I want to do the same thing in python.
I have gone through Boost,SWIG etc but it seems complicated to my newbie Python eyes.
Can the python wizards here kindly point me in the right direction.
I need to call this C++ function from inside a Python function.

Comment: What did you struggle to do with boost.python (I say this because I personally find it the best for this kind of thing)

Comment: This function is literally full of `Rcpp` types, that are not available for python right out of the box. This function must be completely rewritten to be used with python AFAIK.

Comment: It is possible to bridge in some way R and Python through C++, Rcpp and boost.python, but I don't see the advantages... http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-python/

Comment: I'd say one of the easier ways would be wrap your C++ function into C callable (convert c++ class instances into c compatible types), then use cdll python library to call it from Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Since I think the only real answer is by spending some time in rewriting the function you posted, or by writing a some sort of wrapper for the function (absolutely possible but quite time consuming) I'm answering with a completely different approach...

Without passing by any sort of compiled conversion, a really faster way (from a programming time point of view, not in efficiency) may be directly calling the `R` interpreter with the module of the function you posted from within python, through the python `rpy2` module, as described [here](https://sites.google.com/site/aslugsguidetopython/data-analysis/pandas/calling-r-from-python). It requires the `panda` module, to handle the data frames from `R`.

The module to use (in python) are:

```
import numpy as np  # for handling numerical arrays
import scipy as sp  # a good utility
import pandas as pd  # for data frames
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr  # for importing your module
import rpy2.robjects as ro  # for calling R interpreter from within python
import pandas.rpy.common as com  # for storing R data frames in pandas data frames.
```

In your code you should import your module by calling `importr`

```
importr('your-module-with-your-cpp-function')
```

and you can send directly commands to `R` by issuing:

```
ro.r('x = your.function( blah blah )')
x_rpy = ro.r('x')
type(x_rpy)
# => rpy2.robjects.your-object-type
```

you can store your data in a data frame by:

```
py_df = com.load_data('variable.name')
```

and push back a data frame through:

```
r_df = com.convert_t_r_dataframe(py_df)
ro.globalenv['df'] = r_df
```

This is for sure a workaround for your question, but it may be considered as a reasonable solution for certain applications, even if I do not suggest it for "production".